# Android recipe manager + linux server?

Tags: linux, android

I have a growing number of (cooking) recipes on my Linux system, and it would be handy if I could sync them with my mobile. I have tried several from Google Play, but they are riddled with adverts and tied to commercial platforms with too much noise (I just need a practical tool, not a social media app, which many seem to aspire to be).

The subject says it all, really: Is there any decent, simple recipe manager app, which can sync with a server running on my Linux system, which doesn't come with a lot of extra fluff and doesn't require a live connection to a server?

Comment: Have you consider using MS Notes?

Comment: By recipes, are you talking about cooking recipes? In that case you might wish to take a look at Nextcloud Cookbook. That's an app runnin on your Nextcloud. There are several companion apps available for Android. My favorite one (the one I use) is [Nextcloud Cookbook](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.micmun.android.nextcloudcookbook/) – which has no network access itself but simply accesses the files synced from the Nextcloud instance. It's rather a viewer, but that's totally fine with me; editing recipes is much easier on a big screen with a real keyboard anyway :D

Comment: @RomeoNinov No I haven't; it sounds like a Microsoft product - does it run on Linux?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, this is for cooking recipes. Ideally it would be built over a relational database. Thank you for the tip about nextcloud; I'm somewhat sceptical about cloud (I have reason to be: I work with cloud every day, you see) - there are always terms and conditions that boil down to "You pay us and sign over your soul".

Comment: @j4nd3r53n, yes it is MS products, yes it run on Linux via wine. Natively on Android. It sync via OneDrive (when you register you have 10 GB space i think)

Comment: @Izzy So, how do you edit recipes on your PC?

Comment: Via Web browser. It even fetches recipes from numerous websites (just paste the URL, it parses the recipe and even includes the image, sets up steps etc). You can self-host the server part (Nextcloud) or get it from one of the providers (they offer a list with such).

Comment: @RomeoNinov a notes app is not really suited for recipes. And if one looks for a Linux solution, depending on Wine is quite a stopper for most (not only in terms of performance). Apart from that, many (if not most) Linux users wouldn't really want to use MS products in the first place – especially not if they do not fit the purpose at all. If you want to use a notes app for this, there are other better fitting choices like Carnet, QOwnnotes, Tomboy etc having native Linux versions and syncing in free/libre ways.

Comment: @Izzy, you are right about Notes and Linux. But how much of the applications you mention have Android app with which they can sync? And this app is not directly for recipes, but everyone can build suitable organization in Notes. BTW Carnet do not differ much as organization of information from Notes!

Comment: @Izzy, P.S. I hate this approach of developers to force me to install other package with which i can install desired one. Why they are so lazy and do not build native package....(see CentOS install of Carnet)

Comment: How much of the mentioned? All of them AFAIK. I don't use Carnet. I have used QOwnNotes in the past (syncs with Nextcoud, so there are many Android apps to chose from). Tomboy might be a bit aged indeed. I've used Notes app for recipes in the past; never worked as well as a dedicated recipe app.